# What is the correct way to use object destructing in this situation?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I recently added ESLint to a project to improve the project and my skills.

```
const server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    log.info(`API server listening on host ${host}, port ${port}`);
});
```

ESLint says to use destructuring for line 2 and 3.

The 'quick fix' that VSCode gives me is

```
const server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
    const { host } = server.address();
    const { port } = server.address();
    log.info(`API server listening on host ${host}, port ${port}`);
});
```

This feels... wrong somehow.
If the quick fix isn't actually the correct fix, can someone educate on the *proper* way to use destructuring here.
If this is indeed the correct fix, can someone explain reasons this is better than it was before.

I don't want to blindly follow ESLint but I'm not about to ignore the advice of a tool like ESLint either. Like I said, I want to learn.

Comment: No need to run the `address` method twice: `const { host, port  } = server.address()`

Comment: @adiga
I think it should be.
`const { address, port } = server.address()`
naming is a little misleading but anyway same same but different

Comment: @adiga Almost, you also need to map the field since the variable is different than the field name.

Comment: @Nit you're right. I was referring to the second part of the code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructuring javascript works like this: See the example below:
Let say you define an object `x` having keys `a`, `b`, `c` :

`var x = {a:1, b:2, c:3};`

Now if you want to get only keys `a` and `c` from object `x` and store them in variable and as well as you want to assign key `a` to custom named variable let say it `m` :

`var {a:m, c} = x;`

`console.log(a); // throws error "Uncaught ReferenceError: "a" is not defined"`

`console.log(m); // prints 1`
 here value of "a" gets assigned to variable m

`console.log(c); // prints 3` 
here value of "c" gets assigned to default named variable called "c"

I hope this explains you the working of destructuring in javascript. Below is the implementation of destructuring into your question:

```
const server = app.listen(config.port, () => {
    const { address: host, port } = server.address();
    log.info(`API server listening on host ${host}, port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Help me understand why this is getting downvoted? I want to learn and when I selected it, it seemed to address the issue. What am I not understanding that this this is a bad way to do destructing?

Comment: @jonathanW I didn't downvote, but answers that are simply "Do this" and some code aren't considered good answers on SO — they don't give any context or background into the issue.

Comment: I have updated the explaination also. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

You can destruct the value while also mapping the fields to different names.

```js
const mockServer = {
  address() {
    return {
      address: 'foo',
      port: 3000,
    };
  },
};

const { address: host, port } = mockServer.address();

console.log(host, port);
```

Comment: Can you ELI5 what's happening here? Where does `app.listen()` fit into this now?

Comment: @jonathanW I've renamed the server variable to be more verbosely descriptive of what's going on. The `mockServer` variable is simply a placeholder object in place of your actual server to demonstrate how destructing works.

Comment: Ahh, yea that helps. I thought it might be doing some magic I didn't understand since the orig code assigned something to a `server` variable as well. So your's and @vikash-singh are the same solution. He plugged it in directly, you left me to connect the dots and learn a little more ;)